# C Statistical Analysis Program having mathematical errors

Tags: c, math

I wrote a program in C that does some different calculations with numbers passed through the command-line. For some reason, the result of Average() tends to be something large (and occasionally negative, I'll include a log file) and Std_Dev() tends to print 0. I ahve the code in a repository on GitHub:

https://github.com/Jordan-Effinger/Data-Analysis

A quick notice about the files: in the repository is a file called type.h. That file is not used in my current Build so if you don't see anything defined in there used just a heads up.

Example Results:

main 0 0 0 0 0 
Calculating average
Calculating std-deviation
-141545200 1195973704

main 0 0 0 0 0
Calculating average
Calculating std-deviation
-1030105488 1003883182

main 0 0 0 0 0
Calculating average
Calculating std-deviation
1478538976 1111766907

Any thoughts? I think something's going wrong when the functions are returning the result - but I've used these functions before and I didn't have this kind of problem...

Edit #1:
I realized both functions have a problem with zero. That is something I will have to work on. I looked throught he comments, implemented a few changes there and found a few changes of my own. I won't include the whole functions, just go over the changes.

file: main.c
I dynamically allocated space for Data[], Sorted[] using malloc:

```
` float *Data = (float *) malloc( (data_count + 3 ) * sizeof(float) );
```

In all of the functions ( and their prototypes), I have arrays declared as float * and am passing the data_count variable as a size reference (I'm not quite comfortable with sizeof() in most instances).

file: std_dev.c:
In the for loop I changed

```
sum += pow( Data[data_count] - average, 2 );
```

to

```
sum += pow( Data[index] - average, 2 );
```

I'm going to run some tests, implement the rest of the calculations, and then see what I can do to fix the issue with zero values.

Thank you for your input!

--Jordan.

Comment: Don't post links to code, post the relevant code itself.

Comment: Note that `fprintf( stderr, _ERROR_NO_ARGS_PASSED );` is using a symbol reserved for use by the implementation.  Names starting with an underscore followed by either a capital letter or another underscore are reserved for the implementation for any purpose it chooses.  Names starting with an underscore and a lower-case letter are also reserved, though the scope is a little more restricted.  It is simplest not to create your own symbols that start with an underscore.  This point is widely abused.  Examining system headers will mislead you; they're part of the implementation and must use these.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but even more importantly,
please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).
The code should be shown in the question, and it should be minimal.  You can link to an external resource, but the question should be answerable without reference to the external resource.

Answer (score 3):

I am relatively sure I see a few errors:

1. When calculating standard deviation, you use the parameter `data_count` in the loop body rather than `idx`. That will never work.
2. You are using `Data[data_count]` as the parameter for your array in both the average and standard deviation functions. If you're using C you probably just want `float *Data`. I am pretty sure `Data[data_count]` is simply wrong here. Possibly `float Data[]` might be correct. ***EDIT: it has been pointed out in the comments that this syntax can actually be correct if the compiler supports it. Check to make sure your compiler supports this and, if so, no changes should be needed.***
3. When you call the average and standard deviation functions, you are passing `Data[data_count]`. I am almost sure this must be wrong; `Data[data_count]` is the `(data_count+1)`'th element of `Data`, an array of size `data_count`; so it's not even defined and, if it were, the type is still wrong. I suggest simply passing `Data` here.

I typically work in C++ so these comments may be off the mark but if C is like C++ in these respects then these are definitely issues to look at.

Comment: Note that the `float Data[data_count]` notation in the function parameter lists is valid C99 and C11 if the compiler supports the variable length array (VLA) feature.  You could also write it either of the two ways you mention.  C is not the same as C++.  Points 1 and 3 are spot on -- it is surprising that the code compiles since a `float` is passed where a `float *` is expected.  It would be better to use `double` than `float`, too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I was hesitant about that syntax you mention precisely for the reason that C isn't C++. I am editing the answer to point out that this may not be an issue.